# PRAW: get_new() misses the very first post

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I am trying to create a script that'll notify me of new posts in a sub-reddit. The core of the code is this:

```
sub = r.get_subreddit('indianwriters',fetch=True)
time.sleep(5)
posts = sub.get_new()                
while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(2.5)                
            post = next(posts)
            print post.id,post.title
```

However this is missing the very first post. But when I type this out line by line as follows:

```
sub = r.get_subreddit('indianwriters',fetch=True)
time.sleep(5)
posts = sub.get_new()
post = next(posts)
print post.id,post.title
```

This works correctly. So why doesn't it work in the script?

Comment: What entry are you have issues with specifically? When I run the code above, I get the same first entry for both cases. (unless there is additional relevant code)

Comment: When I run my script, it returns everything from the second post onwards, but when I run it line by line, I get the very first post.

Comment: I don't see the entry with id: 24iqtq 
title: [Community Challenge] Secret Santa Entries

Answer (score 0):

You are reinventing the wheel here. The easiest way to do this is to use a stream. Your code would look as follows:

```
subreddit = reddit.subreddit('indianwriters')
for post in subreddit.stream.submissions():
    print("Found post! Title: " + post.title + " Link: " + post.permalink)
    #Do whatever you want to notify you here.
```